# JS, difference in array matrix and forEach behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I was doing some training tasks for my JS course and I got one where you must implement a function that takes a positive integer (n) and returns a matrix like the one below (5 was passed):

```
[ [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ]
```

I was able to implement the function with the following code:

```
function getIdentityMatrix(n) {
  const mat = new Array(n).fill([]);
  return mat.map((row, index) => {
    row = new Array(n).fill(0);
    row[index] = 1;
    return row;
  });
}
```

But while doing it I found a strange behavior that I can't explain... If I alter the code a little:

```
function getIdentityMatrix(n) {
  const mat = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(0));
  return mat.map((row, index) => {
    row[index] = 1;
    return row;
  });
}
```

It returns a matrix like this:

```
[ [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ]
```

Why would it work that way? It's like the forEach function iterates over all the elements nested inside each row which it shouldn't do.

Thank you for any advise!

Comment: Problem is each index in the outer array contains the same reference to the inner array.

Comment: When you pass a non-primitive to `.fill()`, every index of the array will reference the same object. You have an array of 5 references to the same inner array.

Comment: Since this isn't a complete answer, I'm posting this as a comment. A suitable one-line replacement would be `const mat = [...Array(n).keys()].map(() => Array(n).fill(0))`

Comment: @patrick I'd prefer `Array.from({ length: n }, (_, i1) => Array.from({ length: n }, (_, i2) => +(i1 === i2)));`

Comment: @JonasWilms I'd argue that's even more unreadable than mine, even though it does replace the entire function and not just the erroneous line. Also I just cooked up another one: `[...Array(n).keys()].map(i => Object.assign(Array(n).fill(0), { [i]: 1 }))` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Array is a reference type. When you do

`new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(0))`

first the inner `new Array(n).fill(0)` makes an array size n filled with `0`; next the outer `Array(n).fill` creates an array filled with n references to that inner array.

It doesn't create n inner arrays, just n references to the same array. So when you change an element of that inner array, all the references in the outer array will reflect the change since they all point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is equivalent to this:

```js
let n = 5
let innerArr = new Array(n).fill(0)

function getIdentityMatrix(n) {
  const mat = new Array(n).fill(innerArr);
  return mat.map((row, index) => {
    row[index] = 1;
    return row;
  });
}
console.log(getIdentityMatrix(n))
```

Because you are using `fill` you are basically filling that `mat` array with references to the `innerArr` `(which you can see clearly from the above console output)`.

Then you do `row[index] = 1` **for each i** which is changing the **same values (at i index) of the same array**.

Now your working example ... which could be written in a shorter form as:

```js
const getIdentityMatrix = (n) =>
   [...Array(n)].map((row, index) => {
     row = Array(n).fill(0)
     row[index] = 1
     return row
   })

console.log(getIdentityMatrix(3))
```

Clearly `maps` over a newly created and then [`spreaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) array of `n` but **then overwrites each element** with an **entirely new array reference**.

Since that reference is brand new modifying it with `row[index] = 1` produces the expected behavior when we `return the x` from the map.

Another way to achieve this in one line is via `map`, [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [**Object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) like this:

```js
const gm = (n) => [...Array(n)].map((x,i) => 
   Object.values(Object.assign(Object.assign({}, Array(n).fill(0)), {[i]:1})))

console.log(gm(3))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// your example is roughly equivalent to this.
const innerArray = new Array(n).fill(0);
const mat = new Array(n).fill(innerArray);

(mat[0] === mat[1] === innerArray) === true;
```

there is only 1 nested array, not n times array.